# exiten registros en java?

Tags: java, c++, arraylist, registro, guardar

existe algo parecido a los registros de c++ en java? tengo que hacer un ejercicio y me pide que guarde datos en un registro (nombre, edad,etc). Lo hice con un arrayList pero nose si este cuenta como uno, aunque puede guardar muchos datos de distintos tipos.

Comment: Por registro te refieres a los `struct` ???

Comment: ¿o te refieres a un archivo que se guarde?

Comment: en java se usan clases para eso (que al final son objetos). Así que documentate sobre las **java class** . Un saludo

Comment: Hola Nicolas bienvenido, sería interesante que aclares si te refieres a guardar, como algo permanente (tipo archivo de texto) o a algo tipo variable, array, lista, objeto de una clase, porque sino, estaremos jugando a las adivinanzas, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: disculpen si no se entendio mi pregunta, es la primera que hago, me indormare sobre como formular la siguiente para trantar de no tener el mismo inconveniente... y Si a lo que me referia en la pregunta eran los structs, que no sea permanente.

Answer (score 3):

En Java se acostumbra trabajar con objetos, a los cuales les defines sus atributos y métodos, con los que puedes setear y obtener los valores de dichos atributos de tu objeto.

Por ejemplo.

1. Creamos un package (estructuras) donde definiremos nuestros objetos/estructuras .
2. Creamos una clase dentro de ese package (en este caso MiEstructura) con el nombre que deseemos para nuestro objeto, agregamos sus atributos y sus respectivos métodos para asignar y obtener los valores (Setters and Getters).

```
package estructuras;

public class MiEstructura {
    
    String nombre;
    int edad;
    boolean etc;
    
    //se agregan métodos para trabajar con el objeto
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    public boolean isEtc() {
        return etc;
    }
    public void setEtc(boolean etc) {
        this.etc = etc;
    }

}
```

En otro paquete podemos tener una clase donde ocupemos el objeto creado (esto se conoce como instanciar el objeto)

```
package objetos;

import estructuras.MiEstructura;

public class MainEjemplo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        //se instancia el objeto 
        MiEstructura miEstructura = new MiEstructura();

        //asignamos valores con el método set
        miEstructura.setNombre("Nicolas");
        
        //imprimimos el dato asignado obteniendolo con el método get
        System.out.println(miEstructura.getNombre());

    }

}
```

Así es como generalmente se trabaja con objetos en Java.

Usando el IDE Eclipse se vería de esta forma en la perspectiva básica.

[image: Vista en Eclipse]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, lo entendi. Y en el caso de querer ingrese el dato por teclado, donde seria mas conveniente pedir ese dato, en el main o crear un setter en la clase a la cual llamaria y la hago devolver el dato en cuestion

Comment: Cuando uno esta partiendo en Java te enseñan a utilizar el objeto Scanner directamente desde el main, y luego desde algún método. Ya después se empiezan a utilizar otras formas de ingresar datos cuando empiezas a utilizar nuevas librerías y frameworks.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por la ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Desde **Java 14** existen los **records**, que son similares a los **structs** de C++.
Por ejemplo para una persona podemos definir:

```
record Person (String nombre, String direccion) {};
```

Este **record** viene con un constructor con argumentos, de modo tal que podemos crear una persona de la siguiente forma:

```
var person = new Person("Gavilan", "Patagonia");
```

Además se crean getters para acceder a las propiedades, que tienen el mismo nombre de la propiedad.

Entonces para acceder a una propiedad podemos hacer esto:

```
System.out.println(person.nombre);
```

que es similar al operador dot de C++

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, investigare mas sobre record